# How could i send notfication app to web in node js i am new to nodejs please if you can

Tags: node.js, push-notification, notifications

i have to send a notification on  web when a event occurs on app

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ReactJS, you need to use WebSockets. Check [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/websockets-tutorial-how-to-go-real-time-with-node-and-react-8e4693fbf843/) tutorial on how to achieve that.

Comment: i have to send notificaiton when event occurs on app

Answer (score 0):

If the event dispatches from server, you can use Socket.IO, but if there is no hurry in getting notifications you can request in AJAX form every (for example) 5 minutes from client side code, to check if there are any notifs or not.

Comment: bus in this case assume my web fornt is on angular and event occurs on android app when a event occurs on how my front get know about this and push a notfication